# update table directly from json

Tags: postgresql

I have some json as below

```
{"id":21,"name":"Ram","address":"mumbai","mobile":"1234567891"}
```

I have a table in postgres: `tblstudents (id,name,address,mobile)`.

Now I want to update a record in this table directly from the input parameter as per the json above:

```sql
update tblstudents
   set name=[name value from json],
   address=[address value from json]
 where id=[id value from json]
```

Actually this is a PUT request, and the parameter is sent as json from front end in postgres function. I want to update table using this json.
How can I achieve this functionality or what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you have done so far? please refer to Please refer to
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: simply I want to update tblstudent table(id,name,address,mobile) in postgress database using json parameter sent from front end. 
Json sent from front end is as below:
{"id":21,"name":"Ram","address":"mumbai","mobile":"1234567891"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jsonb_populate_record function to create the appropriate record.  Postgres implicitly creates a type for your table, so you can use this:

```
UPDATE tblstudents
  set name = json_record.name,
  address = json_record.address
FROM jsonb_populate_record(null::tblstudents, 
     '{"id":21,"name":"Ram","address":"mumbai","mobile":"1234567891"}'::jsonb) 
     as json_record
WHERE json_record.id = tblstudents.id;
```